# Create own ovpn file from using certificate and key

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, openvpn, vpn

I installed OpenVPN on a RPi server. For sample certificates I used the command `pivpn -a`, as suggested by OpenVPN. But now I want to create my own certificates because I need to insert on them an expiration date for examples.

After much research on the Internet, I didn't find anything which works, because the most of the examples provides from users are old version of OpenVPN, the only thing that I learned was that I need openSSL for creating my certificates.

So I ran the below commands for creating my certificates:

```
sudo openssl req -new -key ca.key > mycert.csr
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 1 -in ./mycert.csr /
-signkey /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/ca.key -out some.crt
```

ca.key is the key generated when I installed OpenVPN. 
At this point I tried to combine certificates and key such as many tutorials suggest:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote <my_server_ip> 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name <server_name> name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#my ca.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#the some.crt file, which i created before
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
#No idea what i have to write there
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
#my ta.key
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

I am stuck to this point, because in the section of encrypted private key someone says that there I have to put client.key, so the key which I used for sign my certificate, but it doesn't work.

Did I mess some steps, or this is the wrong way to achieve which I want?